# Matlab out of memory. Error using pdistmex

Tags: matlab, knn, imputation, pdist

I have a matrix M of size(262322x4). On running knn imputation:

```
M=csvread("C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\DATA\B.csv",1,0);
B = transpose(M);
A = knnimpute(B,1);
C=transpose(A);
```

I get the following error:

```
>>knn_imputation
Error using pdistmex
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in pdist (line 264)
Y = pdistmex(X',dist,additionalArg);

Error in knnimpute (line 162)
distances = pdist(dataNoNans',metric,distargs{:});

Error in knn_imputation (line 4)
A = (knnimpute(B,1));
```

Is this error due to Memory limitations or something else?

(Note: Memory size: 8GB)

Comment: We can't reproduce youy situation since we don't have your csv file. Did you try to type `help memory` like it's said and consider the options?

Comment: As stated in the error, `knnimpute` uses `pdist`, the pairwise distance... I'm not sure whether that's pairwise for every one of your 262322*4 (=1049288) elements, but if so then a matrix of doubles 1049228^2 in size is hundreds of GB, clearly not going to fit in RAM. You will have to segment the problem, or use a different approach.